# Extracting bit-shifted numbers in the middle of a BIGINT with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bit-shift

A coworker came up with an internal ID that combines multiple different identifiers, all bitshifted together.

I'm trying to get out the "TotalSeconds" from this `BIGINT` using T-SQL. The only way I can think of offhand to do is to do an AND against the number that would be bits 21(?) to 50, and convert that back to an INT, and then use dateadd to get the time.

Specifically, this part:

```
StartUTC = new DateTime(BaseYear, 1, 1).ToUniversalTime();
TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - StartUTC;
...(one of the identifiers)
+ (((ulong) timeSpan.TotalSeconds % 1073741824L) << 20) + // 30 bits.
...(another of the identifiers)
```

Comment: Aside: You can use [`Power`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/power-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) rather than a _magic number_ for powers of two. And bitwise AND is [`&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in TSQL.

Comment: @HABO Knew about the bitwise AND, but wasn't sure if my logic worked or made sense, and wanted to get it asked before I dinked around with it excessively, rather than try and reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Bitwise AND only works up to 32-bit values, so you'll want to divide first. (Modulus (`%`) works for 64-bit values.) It works for all of the sample data you provided.

Comment: @HABO Well, I thought I got this, but... . (and thanks for the bit about AND only working up to 32-bit).   So, if my number is 184850504567886584, I divide by 2^20 (1048576), or modulo it by the same value (which... I'm confused about, since it seems like they would give similar numbers but don't),and I get either 135928 or 176287178581.12963104. if I take the second one and try to AND it with 2^31, I still get an error because the leading bits are in there. Maybe I need to modulo again?

Comment: @HABO - okay, I think I'm figuring it out.  : )  Modulo by 2**51 (or 2**50, unsure which) to get out the high bits, then divide by 2**20 (?) to get rid of the low bits, and what's left is my number.

Comment: Division is equivalent to right-shifting (with the result being the _quotient_). Bitwise AND takes a bitmask and modulo takes a divisor (with the result being the _remainder_). For example, to get the 8 least significant bits you could `& 255` (aka `& ( Power( 2, 8 ) - 1 )`) or `% 256` (aka `% Power( 2, 8 )`).

Comment: To extract `@Width` bits starting `@Offset` bits from the LSB: `declare @Sample as BigInt = 184850504567886584; declare @Offset as Int = 20, @Width as Int = 30; select @Sample as OriginalValue, @Sample / Power( 2, @Offset ) as RightShifted, ( @Sample / Power( 2, @Offset ) ) % Power( 2, @Width ) as MaskedSeconds, DateAdd( second, ( @Sample / Power( 2, @Offset ) ) % Power( 2, @Width ), 0 ) as SomeTime;`. SQL Server doesn't have a `TimeSpan` equivalent. `Time` is limited to time-of-day, i.e. < 24 hours.

Comment: @HABO, dude, that's it! I obviously was doing something wrong, but yours worked exactly - many thanks!  (If you want the points, put it as the answer and I'll happily vote for it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: SQL Server does not cope gracefully with unsigned integers.

Division by a power of two is equivalent to right-shifting, e.g. `Foo >> 3` in C# would be `Foo / Power( 2, 3 )` in TSQL. It works with integer types up to 64-bits.

Bitwise AND ([`&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) and modulus ([`%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) can be used with powers of two, but they are not interchangeable. To extract the five least-significant-bits you could use either `Foo % Power( 2, 5 )` or `Foo & ( Power( 2, 5 ) - 1 )`. The first returns the remainder after division by 0x20 and the second masks off the unwanted bits using a mask of 0x1F. There are two important differences to keep in mind: (1) bitwise AND is limited to 32-bit values while modulus works up to 64-bits and (2) if the original value is negative then the signs of the results differ:

```
select 10 % 4 as ModPos, 10 & 3 as AndPos, -10 % 4 as ModNeg, -10 & 3 as AndNeg;
```

Putting it all together, you can extract a bitfield of `FieldWidth` bits starting `FieldOffset` bits from the LSB of a `BigInt` value by dividing the original value to move the bits of interest to the least significant bits, then masking off any unwanted bits:

```
( OriginalValue / Power( 2, FieldOffset) ) % Power( 2, FieldWidth )
```

The original question involves converting the resulting `NumberOfSeconds` into a `TimeSpan`. The closest TSQL datatype is [`Time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and it is limited to values less than 24 hours, i.e. a time-of-day. If the value is within the range of `Time` you can convert it thusly:

```
Cast( DateAdd( second, NumberOfSeconds, 0 ) as Time )
```

Comment: For my future reference: if power gets to be too big with the bitshifting (I needed to do "power(2,57)" and it threw errors, you can do "POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT),CAST(57 AS BIGINT))" and it will work.